# How to get a String-Array of the whole ListView

Tags: android, arrays, string, listview, android-listview

I have a `ListView` with dynamically added `TextViews` and how do I get all `TextView` objects of the `ListView` in a `String-Array` ?
For testing I would like to display the whole `String-Array` in my `Toast` in the `onItemClick`method

onCreate:

```
final ListView sessionLv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.session_list);
        sessionLv.setAdapter(sessionAdapter);
        sessionLv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView c = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.stepTime);
                String playerChanged = c.getText().toString();


                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        playerChanged +" wurde angeklickt!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                toast.show();

                }
        });
```

The `adapter` for the dynamically added `TextView` objects in my `ListView`

```
 class SessionItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Map> {

        ArrayList<Map> values;
        Context context;

        SessionItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Map> values) {
            super(context, R.layout.session_list_layout_row, values);
            this.values = values;
            this.context = context;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.session_list_layout_row, parent, false);

            TextView tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.stepTime);
            final int rowId = (Integer) values.get(position).get("id");
            int beepStringId = getResources().getIdentifier("exercise_typ_" + values.get(position).get("type"), "string", getPackageName());

            rowView.setTag(rowId);

            tv.setText(getResources().getString(beepStringId));

            ImageButton deleteSession = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.session_item_del);
            deleteSession.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    /*if (!startStopToggle.isChecked()) {*/
                        sessionAdapter.remove(values.get(position));
                    sessionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                }
            });

            return rowView;
        }
```

Comment: Hi, from your code i understood that you want to display all the strings of all your TextViews, why don't you use the adapter to get the whole Strings, you can add a function and iterate over your list of values and return the strings from each map just like you did in getView

Comment: could you please make an example ? I searched for some hours now and can't found anything. Is it something with `getCount` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help,

```
//in your item click
sessionLv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        SessionItemAdapter adapter = (SessionItemAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
        List<String> allPlayers = adapter.getAllPlayers();

        // Log your list or whatever you want to do with it
        Log.i(TAG, "allPlayers: " + allPlayers.toString());

    }
});
//in your adapter getAllPlayers() would be something like this
public List<String> getAllPlayers(){
    List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Map item : values) {           
        int beepStringId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("exercise_typ_" 
        + item.get("type"), "string", context.getPackageName());
        String str = context.getResources().getString(beepStringId);
        list.add(str);
    }
    return list;
}
```

---

Comment: I want to pass that `List<String>` now from my `Activity` to a `Fragment`. But it does not work. I post it as a new answer here, maybe you can help me why it does not work.